validation should run after all other pre-update hooks
I am trying to update a user document
const userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  password: String,
  confirmPassword: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function (val) {
        if (this instanceof mongoose.Query) {
          const data = this.getUpdate();
          return val === data.$set.password;
        }else{
            return val===this.password;
      }
    }
  }
})
userSchema.pre("save",async function(next){
   this.password=await bcrypt.hash(this.password,12);
   next();
})
userSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function (next) {
  const data = this.getUpdate();
  if (data.password) {
    data.password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 12);
  }
  next();
});

but what happens is that the password is  encrypted before the validation porcess...but if I use the doc.save method it works fine
